# Axiom of choice for singletons

Tags: logic, axiom-of-choice

Let $\mathscr C \subseteq \mathscr P (\mathbb R )$ be a family of singletons, i.e.: each element of $\mathscr C$ contains exactly one real number. Let $f: \mathscr C \to \mathbb R $ be  the function that for each element $C \in \mathscr C $ selects its element, i.e. $f(C) \in C$.

Is $f$ ***well defined***? Does one need to appeal to some form or the axiom of choice to define $f$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to appeal to the axiom of choice.

Since there is only one choice from each singleton, you can essentially write down the function explicitly:

$$\Big\{\big\langle A,x\big\rangle\mathrel{}\Bigm|\mathrel{} x\in A\in\mathscr C\Big\}.$$

Since each $A$ is a singleton, it appears in *exactly* one ordered pair, so it is indeed a function whose domain is $\mathscr C$, and it is easy to see that it is a choice function.

Note that it didn't even matter that the singletons were real numbers. In the case of the real numbers, or generally any linearly ordered set, you can choose from finite subsets uniformly by noting that every finite subset has a minimal (and maximal) element in the given linear order. So we can pick that.

Comment: I do not follow this part 'you can essentially write down the function explicitly ...'. Here you define a set of ordered pairs, where each $A$ appears exactly once. Can this set be interpreted as the function itself? Are functions interpreted as a special type of sets of ordered pairs? Also, if for all elements in the domain, there is a canonical way or specified way to assign (choose) values for the function, does this resolve the existence question without using any form of AC?

Comment: I think that all of your questions here are really just "what does being a function mean in the context of set theory".

Comment: Thanks! Your characterization is on point. I think this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4402642/well-formed-formulas-and-functions-in-set-theory  partially answered my question, where it states a function is defined as a subset of the product of the domain and image. However, another part of my confusion is that whether a ‘manual’ construction of an object naturally resolve the existence question of the very object. I guess the answer has to be yes, but am having difficulty to digest this.

Comment: Most people are confused by the lack of manual constructions when it comes to choice functions. It's unusual to see someone being confused by the other end of the stick. :-)